# Duplicate number in List remove in python

Tags: python

I just want simple list which remove duplicate digit

```
a = [2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,0]
m = []
def single_digit_list(a):
    return [m.append(x) for x in a if x not in m]
```

print "New List", single_digit_list(a)

I was expected that new list gave me the one digit in list not repeated but i got following output

**New List [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]**

I can't understand what going on

**Simple Know what is wrong in code**

Comment: I updated my answer to answer your question

Comment: list.append does not return anything. So list of m.append results would be a list of None. Try `[(m.append(x), x)[1] for x in a if x not in m]`.

Comment: @werehuman Don't suggest that. Having side effects in LC is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use set to remove duplicates:

```
 m=set(a)
```

If you wanted output to be list:

```
m=list(set(a) )
```

Your code is good..You just have to return m...instead of returning return value of append...For ex, `print m.append(10)` will print `None` which is actually append's return value,you are not printing m.

You could modify you code as follows to return list:

```
a = [2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,0]
def single_digit_list(a):
    m = []
    [m.append(x) for x in a if x not in m]
    return m #you have appended elements to m
```

Comment: Thank's for your quick answer but i just want to know that what is wrong in code

Comment: Your code is good..You just have to return m...instead of returning return value of append...For ex, print a.append(10) will print None which is actually append's return value,you are not printing a.

Comment: `list(set(a))` is probably the best way to go. Using list comprehensions just to run commands and throw it away can't be pythonic though.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to return a list of lists where all the lists are None.
This is because `m.append()` does not return anything and you are trying to create a list of what `m.append` **returns**
Just do it as:

```
def single_digit_list(a):
    m = []
    for x in a:
        if x not in m:
            m.append(x)
    return m

>>> print single_digit_list([2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,0])
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

Comment: Thank's for your detail explanation that cause is m.append().So can you please tell me any another way to do it because I just want to learn in combine for and if statement as in code.

Comment: @user3459261, Either as I have shown in my answer above or as user3 suggested (first answer)

Answer (score 1):

If your list is already grouped, you can use [groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
>>> x = [1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> print [i[0] for i in groupby(x)]
[1, 4, 5, 2, 3]
```

This solution does not break order of element instead of converting to set.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you got list of `None` value is :

1. List comprehension is use to generate a list base on the return of the `expression` given inside the list comprehension.

Eg: `[ expression for item in list if conditional ]`

So, in your case you are appending an item into a list, which return None after appending the item if it was appending successfully.

Eg:

```
>>> ls = []
>>> print ls.append('a')
None
>>>
```

So, at the end of your list comprehension, your list `m` got the correct unique element list but you return the list generate by the comprehension which is a list of `None` value.

Conclusion:

You can fix that by return the value of `m` not the result of list comprehension.

Or here is another easy solution using dictionary key:

```
>>> a = [2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,0]
>>> dict.fromkeys(a).keys()
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```